# change cache location path for APT

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

When using `apt`, can I tell it to use other then `/var/cache/apt` location?
I tried adding the following line in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
% cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
Dir::Cache /home/apt
```

and re-run `apt` but it still writes in `/var/cache/apt`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add one of the following lines to any file inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` or to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Dir::Cache{Archives /home/apt/}
Dir::Cache::Archives /home/apt;
```

This will store all partially/full downloaded `.deb` files inside `/home/apt`.

```
Dir{Cache /home/apt}
Dir::Cache /home/apt;
```

This will store `pkgcache.bin`, `srcpkgcache.bin` inside `/home/apt` and all partially/full downloaded `.deb` files inside `/home/apt/archives`

Remember to add enough privileges to `_apt` user to that directory, so that everything works properly.

You can see the whole configuration of `apt` with `apt-config dump`, for example:

```
> apt-config dump | grep Dir::Cache
Dir::Cache "/home/apt";
Dir::Cache::archives "archives/";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "srcpkgcache.bin";
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "pkgcache.bin";
```

Comment: btw, if we specify a different location for archives , that could be other than the local sd card auto clean or clean using apt-get may not be required.

Comment: This is confusing. You give to sets of lines. Which set is appropriate?

Comment: If you want to cache as muich as possible, you probably want - Dir::Cache /home/apt;

Comment: It's also confusing why each setting appears twice, once inside curlies and once with ::